# Change legend generated by bal.plot

Tags: r

I did a propensity analysis on patient population for a factorial variable which can take 1/0

```
m.out = matchit(MatchedVar ~ Property1+Property2+Property3
                , data = PropensityDB, method = "nearest", ratio = 1)
```

And want to plot the new distribution of distance from the mean.
I do this by calling

```
bal.plot(m.out,var.name = "distance", which = "both")
```

and get the following graph:

[image]

I would like to change the "Treatment" title to something else to properly name the groups.

Tried several ways but could not solve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

bal.plot creates a ggplot object which can be manipulated as all ggplot objects:

```
p <- bal.plot(m.out,var.name = "distance", which = "both")
p + scale_fill_discrete(name = "MatchedVar")
```